# cakephp saving multiple dynamic generated drop-down list to database

Tags: arrays, cakephp

I have two drop down list and a textbox which can be dynamically added to my form with a button click as many times as possible, but my problem is the array of data from the dynamic form elements are not saving to my database table at a single submit. Below is the structure of the array on debug.

****current array****

```
array(
    'DrugTransaction' => array(
        'drug_type_id' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '1'
        ),
        'drug_id' => array(
            (int) 0 => '1',
            (int) 1 => '2'
        ),
        'quantity' => array(
            (int) 0 => '15',
            (int) 1 => '21'
        )
    )
)
```

**I want the array to look like the sample below**

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [drug_type_id] => 1 
        [drug_id] => 2 
        [quantity] => 14 

    )  
    [1] => Array ( 
        [drug_type_id] => 3 
        [drug_id] => 4 
        [quantity] => 100      
    )  
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
$result = array();

foreach($yourArray['DrugTransaction'] as $key => $subArray)
{

    foreach($subArray as $index => $value)
    {
        $result[$index][$key] = $value;
    }

}
```

edit: I think you also want id set to null, so you have to do something like:

```
foreach($result as $key => $value)
{
    $result[$key]['id'] = null;
    $result[$key]['supplydate'] = '2014-03-31';
}
```

Comment: It is now saving the data but it only saves the last record in the array list. thanks

Comment: I think it's because you have to set `'id' => null` in every array element othrwise cake save the first item and then update it with data from next items. see my edit

Comment: THanks @arilia I used saveAll to get the data saved and another thing, how about if i wanted to add thesame element to each of the array index like; [supplydate] => 12/12/2014 .

Comment: this is how i want it to look like ===                                     array(
 (int) 0 => array(
  'drug_type_id' => '1',
  'drug_id' => '1',
  'quantity' => '14'
  'supplydate' => '2014-03-31'
 )
 
)

Comment: it is exactly what I did